# Jenkins builds are deleted

Tags: hudson, integration, jenkins, continuous

I am using Jenkins..After specifying **repository URL** and credentials When i click build now, its building new build and store it as zip file in workspace.. When i change the **repository url** and giving invalid url, build fails. After this if i give correct **repository url it deletes old builds**.. **I want to retain old builds even after altering the repository URL**.. In build history it show all the build details but if i see the build location after specifying invalid url(save and build) and followed by valid url(save and build). it deletes all the builds and checks out the code.

**I want to retain old builds even after altering the repository URL** How to do this ?? any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workspace is a temporary thing — you should not be storing build artifacts there.

Instead, you should tell Jenkins to archive your artifacts (i.e. your zip file) after each build: select "Archive the artifacts" in the "Post-build steps" section.

Then the zip file from each build will be visible on the web page for that build in Jenkins.